# Pass String to Parse query from spinner

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-spinner

I've got a spinner with a list of states in an array that when a user selects it currently outputs which state they selected to the log, this is working as expected.  The issue I'm facing now is when a user clicks a button once they have selected their state is pulling the data that pertains to that state from parse.  My code is below:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    // Add your initialization code here
    com.parse.Parse.initialize(new com.parse.Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .applicationId("appidhere")
                    .clientKey("clientkeyhere")
                    .server("http://server.compute-1.amazonaws.com:80/parse/")
                    .build());

    // find spinner object here
    final Spinner locSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.locSpinner);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.state_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    locSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    locSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   final int position, long id) {
            Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            final String item = locSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Button search = (Button) findViewById(searchBtn);
            final TextView txtState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtState);
            final TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);

            search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(item);
                    query.whereStartsWith("Name", "Paws");

                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Log.v("item", "Retrieved " + item.toString() + " state");
                                txtState.setText(item);
                                txtName.setText(item);
                            } else {

                                Log.d("item", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

I have initialized parse in onCreate but it am having trouble getting it to populate my TextView's with the fields.  For right now all I'm trying to accomplish is getting the values returned and outputting it to log, but ultimate goal is to be able to have the values show up in the TextViews.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you set a button click listener within a spinner selection listener?

Comment: That code could be wrong (I'm definitely an amateur coder), I'm trying to take the value of what the user selects in the spinner, then once they click the button have it query parse for the selected value of the spinner and return the values.

Comment: You can save the Spinner selection as a member variable (or field) of your class. And you can move out the button click listener to set up in onCreate. I'm not sure if it'll help, but it would look cleaner. At the moment, you're recreating a new button event every spinner selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, you can have parse log what it's doing like this:

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId(appId)
                .clientKey("")
                .server(serverUrl)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new ParseLogInterceptor())
                .build()
```

You will also need this in your gradle file:

`compile 'com.parse:parseinterceptors:0.0.2'`

Most likely you're getting an HTML response, like a 404 or 500 or something like that, rather than the JSON that the parse SDK is expecting.  403 Not Authorized (off the top of my head, I might have the wrong code) is also common if the URL or application id is wrong.  By logging the details you can see the URL it's using to initialize parse, and exactly what the response is in logcat.

Edit: in your state class define a method like this:

```
public String getName() {
   return getString("name");
}
```

Then do this:

```
textView.setText(state.getName());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've updated my question with some updated code. I'm now running into the issue where it's returning the state but it's updating my textview with the state, not the field I want. Essentially I've got a class which is called State, I want to return a field from within the state class which is (name) and fill in a textview.

Comment: You're going to get whatever `State.toString()` outputs.  So either make that output what you need, or call something like `state.getName()`

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding correctly, apologize but I'm not that experienced.  How do I get it to output what I need?  All I'm trying to do is pass what the user selects in the spinner which in this case is a State which in parse is a class, query parse from a button click with what they selected and then return a field String which is defined as Name.